# How to add Listview in tab activity?

Tags: android, listactivity, tabactivity

I have one "SubjectTabActivity" and i need to show listview on this activity.
But when i want to implement ListActivity it doesn't show listActivity.
I have two(addchapter,addsubject) xml file with "SubjectTabActivity". and i need to
show my database item il list view in respective xml file. but i don't understand
how to do that?
How to add Listactivity in TabActivity?.
Please give me any reference or code.
Thanks in advance..
Here is my reference code.

```
public class MasterMainActivity extends TabActivity 
{
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.master);
     Intent intent=getIntent();
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabHost.TabSpec tab1spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabOneSpec");        
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject);
        tab1spec.setIndicator("Subject", imgView.getBackground());
        tab1spec.setContent(new TabContentLayout());

        TabHost.TabSpec tab2spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabTwoSpec");
        tab2spec.setContent(new TabContentLayout());
        ImageView imgView1 = new ImageView(this);
        imgView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chapter);
        tab2spec.setIndicator("Chapter", imgView1.getBackground());   
        tabHost.addTab(tab1spec);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2spec);          
      }
            private class TabContentLayout implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View view = null;
            if(tag.equals("tabOneSpec"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
                    //  "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
                        //"Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

                    view = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.subjecttabview, null);
                    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.subjecttabview,FRUITS));

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   

            }
            if(tag.equals("tabTwoSpec"))
            {
                try
                {

                    view = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chaptertabview, null);    

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
            return view;
        }
    }
```

> How to add ListActivity in this TabActivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492162/android-listview-inside-tab-layout-inside-dialog-cant-get-scroll-bars-to-show-u refer this link...

Comment: Also see this tutorial...http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59

Comment: Try not to use TabActivity, its deprecated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often times when creating an activity with tabs, 
it’s easy to have a separate activity for the tab content.
However, things get tricky when those activities need to
 interact with one another.

So the solution is to create a tabactivity with views 
(instead of activities) as the tab content.
To create the TAB, there are a few steps we need to follow:

1. create the tabHost and set its parameters
2. create the tabWidget, the container for the clickable tabs
3. create a frameLayout, to hold the views associated to each tab
4. create each tab, using the tabSpec class

and see these links ,  would help you

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59

and

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/tab-control/

and

http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1132

Comment: The second link from the post is really useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

you could just inflate a ListView or create on programatically and add it to the view (LinearLayout) which seems to be your root. Afterwards just add the Adapter to the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Take `ListView` inside your XML layout.

And then find it by their ID inside the TabActivity:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```